# Issue in Hosting React App on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I am trying to host the react app in heroku...

I have created the app using create-react-app..And follow the following methods in hosting...

```
        git init
        heroku create $APP_NAME --buildpack https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
        git add .
        git commit -m "Start with create-react-app"
        git push heroku master
        heroku open
```

But when I am trying to push the app to heroku it returns the following error...

```
      remote:   - htmlparser.js:235 new HTMLParser
      remote:     [build_4acd980d8a80e0486da141a82d0b3cee]/[html-minifier]/src/htmlparser.js:2    35:13
      remote:   
      remote:   - htmlminifier.js:946 minify
      remote:     [build_4acd980d8a80e0486da141a82d0b3cee]/[html-minifier]/src/htmlminifier.js    :946:3
      remote:   
      remote:   - htmlminifier.js:1299 exports.minify
      remote:     [build_4acd980d8a80e0486da141a82d0b3cee]/[html-minifier]/src/htmlminifier.js    :1299:10
      remote:   
      remote:   - index.js:296 
      remote:     [build_4acd980d8a80e0486da141a82d0b3cee]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:296:    16
      remote:   
      remote:   - util.js:16 tryCatcher
      remote:     [build_4acd980d8a80e0486da141a82d0b3cee]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23  
      remote:   - promise.js:512 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
      remote:     [build_4acd980d8a80e0486da141a82d0b3cee]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:51    2:31
      remote:   
      remote:   - promise.js:569 Promise._settlePromise
      remote:     [build_4acd980d8a80e0486da141a82d0b3cee]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:56    9:18
      remote:   
      remote:   - promise.js:614 Promise._settlePromise0
      remote:     [build_4acd980d8a80e0486da141a82d0b3cee]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:61    4:10
      remote:   
      remote:   - promise.js:693 Promise._settlePromises
      remote:     [build_4acd980d8a80e0486da141a82d0b3cee]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:69    3:18
      remote:   
      remote:   - async.js:133 Async._drainQueue
      remote:     [build_4acd980d8a80e0486da141a82d0b3cee]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:133:    16
      remote:   
      remote:   - async.js:143 Async._drainQueues
      remote:     [build_4acd980d8a80e0486da141a82d0b3cee]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:143:    10
      remote:   
      remote:   - async.js:17 Immediate.Async.drainQueues
      remote:     [build_4acd980d8a80e0486da141a82d0b3cee]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:17:1    4
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have a procfile file in your directory? It should be there to tell Heroku how to start your app. In the procfile, You'd put something like: web: npm start. In the Heroku CLI, try running heroku logs --tail to get some more error information.

Comment: @CrissiMariamRobert: I think the problem is when you build. Can you try building with `yarn build` or `npm run build` and see if that throws an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just cloned your repo and tried `npm install` + `npm run build`. I found that `npm run build` fails locally. So, this is an error with the code, not with Heroku deployment.

The failure is from `HTMLParser`, so I looked at the `public/index.html` and found a heavily customized template.

To check if that `public/index.html` content was the problem, I replaced it with the default create-react-app HTML template code. Then, `npm run build` completed successfully.

So, it seems **there is a problem with the validity of the HTML in your `public/index.html`** which breaks create-react-app's template engine. I suggest running it through an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org) to find problems, or manually breaking the template into smaller testable pieces until you find the part that causes the build error.